# Programmatically export VBA modules

Tags: java, vba, vbscript

To transfer a VBA macro between different PowerPoint files, I can export the module as a BAS file and then import it into the other file. This has to be done manually, however.

My Java 1.8 application will automatically generate new PowerPoint files using Apache POI, then call a VBScript. The script will receive arguments from the Java application via the command line, and will then open the created PowerPoint file and call a macro, finally passing the parameters to the macro.

Before all that can happen, I need to first import multiple macros from a template PowerPoint file into the newly created one automatically. How can I do that using either Java or VBS?

Edit: If you're going to close this for being too broad can you at least tell me how it is not specific enough? Because as far as I can see I've already stated very specifically what I want to achieve. It's my first time coding in VBA or VBS so I don't know what is expected from me to make questions in this topic "specific".

Answer (score 3):

To export all the modules from 1 mother office file, to another .xlsm file:

1. if the workbook that contains the mother macros is located in folder:
   "../a"
2. Then place the child office files in:
   "../a/receiving/
3. And create a(n empty) subfolder:
   "../a/receiving/modules
4. Open the VBA for applications editor in MS Office, click "tools>references" and mark the checkbox: "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"

Next, create two modules,

5. Module1:

   ```vb
   Sub Update_Workbooks()
   'This macro requires that a reference to Microsoft Scripting Routine
   'be selected under Tools\References in order for it to work.
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
   Dim source As Scripting.Folder
   Dim wbfile As Scripting.File
   Dim book As Excel.Workbook
   Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim Filename As String
   Dim ModuleFile As String
   Dim Element As Object
   Dim return_user_input As Integer


   'Set source = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Desktop\Testing")   'we will know this since all of the files will be in one folder
   Set source = fso.GetFolder(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\receiving")   'we will know this since all of the files will be in one folder
   For Each wbfile In source.Files

       Call basic_messagebox(wbfile, return_user_input)
       If return_user_input = 6 Then
           MsgBox (wbfile.name & " yes")

           'For Each wbFile In source.Files

           If fso.GetExtensionName(wbfile.name) = "xlsm" Then  'we will konw this too. All files will be .xlsm
               'Call basic_messagebox
               'Set book = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)
               Set book = Workbooks.Open(wbfile.Path)
                   Filename = FileNameOnly(wbfile.name)
                   'This will remove all modules including ClassModules and UserForms.
                   'It will keep all object modules like (sheets, ThisWorkbook)
                   'On Error Resume Next
                   Workbooks(wbfile.name).Activate
                   'For Each Element In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
                   'On Error Resume Next
                   Call DeleteAllCode(wbfile)
   '                For Each Element In Workbooks(wbfile.name).VBProject.VBComponents
   '                    'ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Element
   '                    Workbooks(wbfile.name).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Element
   '
   '                Next
   '                For Each Module In Workbooks(wbfile.name).VBProject.VBComponents
   '                    Workbooks(wbfile.name).VBProject.VBComponents.Remove Module
   '                Next

                   'On Error GoTo ErrHandle
               '   Export Module1 from updating workbook
                   'ModuleFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\tempmodxxx.bas"
                   ModuleFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\receiving\modules" & "\tempmodxxx.bas"

   '                Workbooks("Update Multiple Workbooks.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents("Module1") _
   '                .Export ModuleFile
                   'On Error Resume Next
                   For Each Module In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
                       'MsgBox (Module.name)
                       If Left(Module.name, 5) <> "Sheet" Then
                           If Left(Module.name, 6) = "Module" Then
                               'MsgBox ("the modules name = " & Module.name)
                               'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").Export ModuleFile
                               ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Module.name).Export ModuleFile
                               'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Module).Export ModuleFile
                               'MsgBox (ModuleFile)
                           '   Replace Module1 in Userbook
                               Set VBP = Workbooks(Filename).VBProject
                               'On Error Resume Next
                               With VBP.VBComponents
                                   .Import ModuleFile
                               End With
                           '   Delete the temporary module file
                               Kill ModuleFile
                           End If
                       End If
                   Next
               'book.Close True
           End If
   'Next


       End If
       If return_user_input = 7 Then
           MsgBox (wbfile.name & " no")
       End If

   Next

   Exit Sub
   ErrHandle:
   '   Did an error occur?
       MsgBox "ERROR. The module may not have been replaced.", _
         vbCritical


   End Sub
   Private Function FileNameOnly(pname) As String
       Dim temp As Variant
       Length = Len(pname)
       temp = Split(pname, Application.PathSeparator)
       FileNameOnly = temp(UBound(temp))
   End Function
   Sub basic_messagebox(wbfile, return_user_input)
       'source: http://www.databison.com/vba-message-box-msgbox-the-message-can-do-better/
       'vbOK = 1
       'vbCancel = 2
       'vbAbort = 3
       'vbRetry = 4
       'vbIgnore = 5
       'vbYes = 6
       'vbNo = 7

       i = MsgBox("Do you wish to force the new code on the following excel file: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & wbfile.name, vbYesNo)
       If i = 6 Then
           'MsgBox (wbFile.name & " yes")
           return_user_input = i
       End If
       If i = 7 Then
           'MsgBox (wbFile.name & " no")
           return_user_input = i
       End If

   End Sub
   ```
6. Module2:

   ```
   Sub DeleteAllCode(wbfile)
        'Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=93
        'Trust Access To Visual Basics Project must be enabled.
        'From Excel: Tools | Macro | Security | Trusted Sources

       Dim x               As Integer
       Dim Proceed         As VbMsgBoxResult
       Dim Prompt          As String
       Dim Title           As String

       Prompt = "Are you certain that you want to delete all the VBA Code from " & _
       ActiveWorkbook.name & "?"
       Title = "Verify Procedure"

       Proceed = MsgBox(Prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, Title)
       If Proceed = vbNo Then
           MsgBox "Procedure Canceled", vbInformation, "Procedure Aborted"
           Exit Sub
       End If

       On Error Resume Next
       With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
           For x = .VBComponents.count To 1 Step -1
               .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(x)
           Next x
           For x = .VBComponents.count To 1 Step -1
               .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.DeleteLines _
               1, .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.CountOfLines
           Next x
       End With
       On Error GoTo 0

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I have indented your code in points 5 and 6, see the edit, that will answer your comment (but maybe you already know how to do it now in 2020)